# SQl Query dynamic variable

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, oracle, oracle11g

By using a dynamic variable i need to change the schema name in my SQL Query.
How do I do it dynamically?

Comment: Which RDBMS is this precisely? And can you add some examples?

Comment: Which DBMS do you use?

Comment: Add more info, and don't tag products not involved - MySQL, SQL Server and Oracle are different products!

Comment: using oracle sql developer. say i am using a schema A and i want to run my query in another environment and it has schema B. my query is having like A.tableName so while running in another environment i don't want to go to every place and change from A.tableName to B.tableName. instead i need to change a variable from A to B so that all the place referring A.tableName is changed to B.tableName.

Comment: Use a substitution variable, as explained here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1179652/how-to-use-a-variable-in-oracle-script-for-the-table-name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming this is a query you're manually running in an Oracle database, you could just use a substitution variable, eg.:

```
select * from &schema..table_name;
```

The first `.` is required to indicate the end of the parameter name, so you do need a second consecutive `.` in order to get the query to work.

If you're needing to reuse the substitution variable across multiple queries in the same script, use && instead, eg.:

```
select * from &&schema..table_name;
```

If you're running your queries as a script, don't forget to put `undefine schema` at the end, so that you will be prompted for a new value when you rerun the script, if it's being rerun in the same session.

Comment: The first . is to show where the end of the parameter is. If you didn't put the second dot in, you'd end up with something like: `select * from schema_nametable_name;` instead of the required `select * from schema_name.table_name`

Comment: I tried this and it asked to enter a substitution variable and if i give any random variable it is not working.

Comment: what do you mean by "any random variable"? Clearly, you need to make sure the value is one of your schema names, otherwise the table won't be found. At least, that's the error I assume you're getting, since you didn't say...

Comment: i got it sorry.my mistake.will this work if more than a table is defined in from clause?will this ask for var name more than once?

Comment: can you tel me what would be the syntax in that case?

Comment: If you change it to a double && then it should work both in sql developer and a sql script. E.g.: `select * from &&schema..table_name;` (if you're running it as a script, don't forget to put `undefine schema` at the end, otherwise you won't be prompted for a value on the next run through in the same session)

Comment: got it..thanks..!! it was helpful.